# How to convert a char* to a number function with a comma (decimal point)?

Tags: c, pow

I  wrote `change()` to help me convert a string to a `double`.

For example: if the string is "5.5", I want the number to be 5.5.  If the string is "0.0", I want the number to be 0.  Another example: "50" to 50.

Now the problem is when I use the `change()` with `pow()` that is in the library math.h, everything works perfectly fine and I tested it with a lot of inputs and all worked perfect.

Example to a test :

`change("5.0")` gives me 5
`change("1.5")` gives me 1.5

Since I can't use the library math I wrote `power()`, but when I test `change()`, now I don't get an output.  I think it is stuck in an infinite loop.

Any help why this thing is happening?

```
double change(char* Point) {
    int count = 0;
    double res = 0;
    while (*Point == '0') {
        Point++;
    }
    while (*Point != '.' && *Point) {
        count++;
        Point++;
    }

    int num1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Point--;
        num1 = (*Point - '0') * (power(10, i));
    }

    int i = -1;
    while (*Point != '.' && *Point) {
        Point++;
    }
    double num2 = 0;
    if (!*Point) {
        return res = (double) num1 + num2;

    }
    Point++;
    while (*Point) {
        num2 = (double) (*Point - '0') * (double) (power(10, i));
        i--;
        Point++;
    }
    res = (double) num1 + num2;

    return res;
}
```

I also wrote the function power:

```
int power(int base,int exp)
{
    int result=1;
    if(exp == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    while (exp != 0)
    {
        result=result*base;
        exp--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "the compiler just doesn't stop running" ??? Really? What compiler?

Comment: What is the point of this? Why not use `sscanf()`?

Comment: i am not allowed to use sscanf

Comment: You call `power` with a negative exponent and this is a real problem. You should be able to find out yourself.

Comment: if i was able to find the problem myself i would'nt ask

Comment: @kasandra I gave you almost the solution: look what happens if you call say `power(10, -3)`.

Comment: yes with the function pow it works perfectly !! i litrally tested it with so many tests and all worked perfectt

Comment: @kasandra if it works with `pow` and if it doesn't work with `power`, where could the problem be?

Comment: so i changed "(exp != 0)" to "(exp > 0)" and now only the first test returns correct value from the two

Comment: maybe the problem is with casting or the type that the function returns ?

Comment: Think carefully about what you expect `power(10,-1)` to return.  How would you get it to return that value?

Comment: As others have said, `power` needs to work correctly with negative exponents. But it doesn't. You need to redesign `power` to work with negative exponents. And to do that it needs to return `double`.  That's your new assignment. The math library `pow` takes two double types and returns a double.

Comment: here is the thing .. the input that is given to us is  always valid .. which means i will never get an input that is negative

Comment: @kasandra sigh, but _you_ call `power` with a negative exponent when you process the fractional part. This is correct, but your `power` function is incorrect. Debug your program.

Comment: @kasandra you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how your own code even works it seems. Your code calls `power` with a negative exponent. That has nothing to do with the input being positive or negative. For example, a positive `0.5` comes from 5 times 10 to the -1 power. The power of 10 here is negative. Did you write that code or did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: no i wrote it myself .. and now i get how stupid i am sorry .. i am gonna try and change the function power to work with negative numbers

Comment: @kasandra You may even post your own answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call the function power(10,i) in the change function,  while i have a negative value. You can fix this by adding an if statement in your power function

```
if (exp < 0) {
    exp = 0 - exp;
    return(1/power(base,exp));
}
```

Edit : you also have to change the power function to return double instead of int

Comment: If `power()` returns an `int`, then this won't work at all.

Comment: but if i change the function to accept double and return double this will work.

Comment: @kasandra Yes, if the function returns a `double` it will work. You can keep `int` arguments as you call the `power` function only with integer values.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert a string to a float using `atof()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   float val;
   char str[20];

   strcpy(str, "98993489");
   val = atof(str);
   printf("String value = %s, Float value = %f\n", str, val);


   return(0);
```

source of code : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm

Comment: I think he want's to write an `atof` like function by himself.

Answer (score 0):

As already established, the problem is this loop will never end if `exp` is less than 0 in your `power` function.

```
while (exp != 0)
{
    result=result*base;
    exp--;
}
```

But your code still won't work if you fix this because you're only ever storing one digit in `num1`

```
num1 = (*Point - '0') * (power(10, i));
```

If you pass in, for example, "50" it'll work fine and you'll get 50 back, but if you pass in "54" you'll also get 50 as you lose the 4.

You need to add the newly calculated digit to the existing value like so.

```
num1 += (*Point - '0') * (power(10, i));
```

You can greatly simplify that first bit of the function and remove the need to use `power` though by realising that as you move through the string, you can just multiple the current value of `num1` by 10 and then add on the new digit. This means you only process the string before the decimal point just once rather than 3 times.

```
int num1 = 0;
for(;isdigit(*Point);Point++) {
    num1 *= 10;
    num1 += *Point - '0';
}
```

I've also replaced `*Point != '.' && *Point` with `isdigit(*Point)` (from "ctype.h") as that ensures that if it encounters something that isn't a number character, it doesn't try turning it into a number - you should stop processing completely at that point.

You could remove the need for `power` completely by using the same idea for calculating `num2` as well since the amount you're dividing `*Point - '0'` also increases by 10 each time.